# Angular PrimeNg Esconder boton clear

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

estoy utilizando el modulo p-calendar de primeNg y me muestra por defecto dos botones al final del calendar Today y Clear. Lo que pasa es que yo no quiero que se muestre el segundo boton clear. Ya he intentado eliminar el boton Clear via css pero no lo he logrado.

Con display: none; Me funciona si lo pongo directamente en el html del browser pero desde el codigo no me hace nada. Por otro lado primeNg solo te da la opcion de esconder los dos botones pero no te da la opcion de elegir cualquieres escondder. Yo quiero mantender el boton Today e eliminar el Clean.

Muchas por la ayuda.

Este es el html generado por primeNg no me deja poner todo el codigo pues hay mas html dentro del p-calendar

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-buttonbar ui-widget-header ng-tns-c10-7 ng-star-inserted" style="">
    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-6">
            <button class="ng-tns-c10-7 ui-button-secondary ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" pbutton="" type="button" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-button-secondary" ng-reflect-label="Today"><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">Today</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-6">
            <button class="ng-tns-c10-7 ui-button-secondary ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" pbutton="" type="button" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-button-secondary" ng-reflect-label="Clear"><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">Clear</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

He metido este selector pero no funciona:

```
.ui-datepicker-buttonbar > div.ui-g div:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar el siguiente codigo CSS, que te esconda el segundo elemento de la clase

```css
.ui-button-secondary:nth-child(2) { display: none; }
```

El chiste es que valides los atributos de los estilos que te genera el componente y puedas definir cual te conviene mas. Sugiero compartas tu codigo para mayor contexto de tu problema.

Comment: Hola gracias he adicionado el html